# Zend Framework Plugins

Tags: zend-framework

Kindly explain the following regarding Zend Framework and how do I know which one to use, and when and where to use them.

```
resources.layout.pluginClass  
resources.frontcontroller.plugins
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first is described on [this page](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.layout.options.html) and allows you to provide a specific layout controller plugin class to override the default

> pluginClass: the front controller plugin class to use when using Zend_Layout with the MVC components. By default, this is Zend_Layout_Controller_Plugin_Layout

The second, described [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.frontcontroller) allows you to register any number of generic [controller plugins](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html)

> plugins: array of front controller plugin class names. The resource will instantiate each class (with no constructor arguments) and then register the instance with the front controller. If you want to register a plugin with a particular stack index, you need to provide an array with two keys class and stackIndex.